# Excel: Keyboard shortcuts to navigate Ribbon Menu Tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, ribbon

Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate between (for example) the Home Tab and the Insert Tab in the ribbon menu in Excel (2010).

Like ctrl+tab in a browser to switch tabs. Pretty sure I've seen somebody do this but have been unable to replicate it.

Comment: http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx#BM1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press and release <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then use the arrow keys <kbd>←</kbd> to move left or use <kbd>→</kbd> to move right.

Official Reference: [Keyboard shortcuts in Excel 2010: Other useful shortcut keys](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx#BM4)

> ARROW KEYS
>
> LEFT ARROW or RIGHT ARROW selects the tab to the left or right when
>   the ribbon is selected. When a submenu is open or selected, these
>   arrow keys switch between the main menu and the submenu. When a ribbon
>   tab is selected, these keys navigate the tab buttons.

Comment: Nice - I didn't know about that. You can also tap Alt to show keyboard shortcuts on each ribbon tab.